# ggplot multiple abline with color legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a scatterplot data set and I'm trying to set on top of that many different linear lines using abline. The problem is that I want each line colored a different way and to appear in the Legend with a given class.

I have the following scatter plot with points colored by group:

```
data = data.frame(x=c(-0.1,0,0.2,1.3,-1.2,-0.5),
                 y=c(-0.8,0,-0.2,1.3,-0.4,0.2),
                 group=c(1,0,0,0,1,1))
g=ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y,color=group))+geom_point()+
   geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
   ggtitle("Scatterplot of Original Points")
```

[image]

Now I want to display different lines on top using a function I created, which takes in the values from my new data set and creates the slopes and intercepts (SKIP THIS AS ITS ONLY HERE FOR YOU TO BE ABLE TO REPRODUCE MY CODE).

```
decision = function(v1,v2,v3) {
  if(v3 == 0) {
    intercept = 0
    slope = -v2/v1
  }
  else {
    p1_intercept = -v3/v1
    p2_intercept = -v3/v2
    intercept = p2_intercept
    slope = (p2_intercept) / (-p1_intercept)
  }
  return( list( slope=slope, intercept = intercept))
}
init_gen = data.frame(ID=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),v1=c(-1,-0.9,0.9,-0.1,1,-0.8,-0.1,0.6,-0.3,0.6), v2=c(-0.7,0.9,-0.3,0.8,0.5,0.1,0.8,0.8,-0.2,0.4),v3=c(0,0.3,-0.9,-0.4,-0.5,0.6,0.3,0.2,1,0.3))

for(i in 1:10) {
  line = decision(init_gen$v1[i],init_gen$v2[i],init_gen$v3[i])
  init_gen$slope[i] = line$slope
  init_gen$intercept[i] = line$intercept
}
```

I then take my previous plot and add on those slopes and intercepts:

```
g+geom_abline(data=init_gen, aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept, linetype=ID))
```

[image]

The problem now is that I want each line to be colored differently, which intuitively might mean to add (color=ID):

```
g+geom_abline(data=init_gen, aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept, linetype=ID,color=ID))
```

But I get the following error

[image]

I've searched and I've found other resources but nothing pertaining to abline() using colors...

Comment: The issue is that you already have a continuous color scale for your points. If you want to add a second color scale have a look at the `ggnewscale` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you already use `color` for your points with a continuous value. One trick here is to use `fill` for points with a `shape = 21`.

```
g=ggplot(data, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(aes(fill=group), shape = 21)+
   geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
   ggtitle("Scatterplot of Original Points")
g+geom_abline(data=init_gen, aes(slope=slope,intercept=intercept, linetype=ID,color=ID))
```

The Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ggnewscale` like @stefan said. It's a great option. Alternatively, you can make a palette.

I used a palette option from the library `viridis`, but you could use something else.

```
dPal = viridis::viridis_pal()(nrow(init_gen))  # palette size matching init_gen

g + geom_abline(data=init_gen, 
                aes(slope=slope,
                    intercept=intercept,
                    linetype=ID),
                    color = dPal)
```

[image]